# Дискорд бот не отвечает

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Решил я пойти рискованным путём и попросил ChatGPT сгенерировать кусочек кода. Суть заключалась в том, чтобы  при решении примера давались деньги. Когда я отвечаю на пример - ничего не происходит. Я поставил команду print(result) и мне даже не напечатало результат в консоль. Помогите пожалуйста! Мозг человека намного умнее этих нейросетей! Вот эта чушь:

```
import random
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
async def earn(ctx):

    user_wallet = await get_user_wallet(ctx.author.id)
    
    # Генерация двух случайных чисел
    num1 = random.randint(1, 100)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 100)
    
    # Сложение чисел
    expression = f"{num1} + {num2}"
    result = num1 + num2
    
    # Задержка команды в 60 секунд
    await ctx.send(f"Решите пример: **{expression}**")
    
    def check(m):
        return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel and m.content.strip().isdigit()

    try:
        # Ожидание ответа от пользователя в течение 60 секунд
        user_answer = await bot.wait_for('message', timeout=60, check=check)
        
        # Проверка правильности ответа
        if int(user_answer.content.strip()) == result:
            user_wallet["balance"] += 10000
            await set_user_wallet(ctx.author.id, "balance", user_wallet["balance"])
            await ctx.send(f"**Правильно! Вы заработали 10 000 монет!**")
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"**Неправильно. Попробуйте еще раз позже.**")
    
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await ctx.send("**Время на решение примера истекло. Попробуйте еще раз позже.**")

@bot.listen("on_command_error")
async def cooldown_message(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await ctx.send(f"**Вы сможете использовать команду `!{ctx.command.qualified_name}` только через {int(error.retry_after)} секунд-(ы)!**")
```